# What can I do with all my brick separators?

Tags: piece-information, building, design, brick-separator

Since LEGO has started adding a [brick separator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=630-3) to each of their larger sets, I have more brick separators than I know what to do with.

[image]

Due to inflation, they also aren't really worth anything to try to sell some of them off (some BrickLink stores even given them free with each order), so what are some other things I can do with them? Any clever builds I can use them in?